# What is the difference between RIA and SPA?

Tags: web-applications, web, single-page-application, ria

What is the difference between a [Rich Internet application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) and a [Single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)?

Answer (score 0):

[RIA](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Rich-Internet-Application-RIA) is way of creating RICH desktop type interface which can be created using stadardise technologies like (x)HTML, CSS and JavaScript and by using embedded technologies like Adobe Flash and Microsoft Siverlight.An RIA normally runs inside a Web browser and usually does not require software installation on the client side to work. Most RIAs run their client portions within a special isolated area of the client desktop called a sandbox. The sandbox limits visibility and access to the file and operating system on the client to the application server on the other side of the connection. This approach allows the client system to handle local activities, calculations, reformatting and so forth, thereby lowering the amount and frequency of client-server traffic, especially as compared to the client-server implementations built around so-called thin clients.
One distinguishing feature of an RIA (in contrast to other Web-based applications) is the client engine that intermediates between the user and the application server. The client engine downloads when the RIA launches. The engine can be augmented during subsequent operation with additional downloads in which the engine acts as a browser extension to handle the user interface and server communications. [More..](http://www.upf.edu/hipertextnet/en/numero-9/ria-and-web-accessibility.html)

Single Page Application are thin client. They are perfectly normal web based application. It interface build in HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. There are many open-source JavaScript frameworks are coming aims to provide better Single page application solution. SPA also aims to provide better user interface, with less frequent client-server communcation. SPA is suitable for desktop applications, but it can be applied to build good mobile websites or hybrid applications. [More information.](https://upvishal.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/memory-management-in-single-page-application/)

Comment: The first paragraph about RIA is contradicting. Engine as a browser extension is applicable to "Flash/Sliverlight" but not to using HTML/CSS/JS.
Also there is no reason to assume that SPA is thin. SPA can really be quite fat with hundreds of Mb of complex logic. It can even act as a standalone in-browser app without backend.